# Mais links para perguntas fechadas por duplicidade

Tags: novo-recurso

Vejo, e também tenho perguntas minhas fechadas por "[duplicada]", e que por minha parte, sim, (desculpe a sinceridade) é o péssimo motor de pesquisa.

Em alguns casos, vê-se que a pergunta referenciada, sim, atende 90% dos casos, mas, ela sempre atende 100% da pergunta!? Na minha opinião: Não.

---

"Ah mas aí coloca nos comentários..."

Mas se já nos comentários tiver conversa, então "cai por terra".

---

Poderia ter uma interface mais "amigável" para lincar mais perguntas e/ou respostas que "completam" a pergunta marcada como duplicada.

Comment: Agora já tem, mas pra usar precisa ter ouro na tag. Aquela sua de PDO eu nao tive tempo de pesquisar ainda, mas pretendo por mais links no fechamento (por isso sugeri você dar uma olhada nas relacionadas na margem da página enquanto isso, para não ficar sem resposta)

Comment: @Bacco Esse negócio da tag ouro aí não sabia! Agora que vc comentou, eu ACHO que já vi algo do tipo... 

Comment: Se a duplicata atende 90% então porque não fazer uma pergunta apenas nos 10% que falta ?

Comment: @Isac Porque não achei nem a dos 90%! Rs

Comment: Se a resposta é tão boa e votada, porque a pergunta foi tão ruim!?... isso é meio confuso...

Comment: @rbz existe até uma medalha para "respostas" que salvam perguntas supostamente ruins, não é que algumas perguntas são ruins pelo tópico, mas são ruins da maneira que foram escritas, então geralmente uma resposta consegue ser tão boa e complementar ao mesmo tempo que acaba ganhando destaque pelo incrivel trabalho de salvamento :) .... [Respostas salva-vidas em serviço](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKQhx.jpg)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento kkkk que medalha é essa?

Comment: @rbz se chama "reversão", no site principal só o maneiro conseguiu ela: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal, no Meta 3 usuários conseguiram ela: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/57/reversal

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Só pra constar antes de responder o que acho relevante, o recurso "adicionar mais links" para duplicatas **já existe**:

> [image: adicionar mais perguntas duplicatas]

A seta a esquerda no topo da imagem indica que você pode arrastar e reposicionar as perguntas na ordem que desejar e a seta a esquerda abaixo mostra o botão <kbd>adicionar</kbd>, clicando nesse botão abre um modal para buscar perguntas ou colar link de uma pergunta.

No entanto somente moderadores e usuários medalha de ouro podem fazer uso disto, ou seja é algo que só pessoas mais "confiáveis" ao sistema podem realizar, o que faz sentido.

Agora vou falar sobre como debater duplicidades...

Pessoalmente acho que você deveria se focar em resolver o problema especifico, ou uma regra nem sempre vai atender 2 perguntas, quero dizer eu expliquei na sua pergunta sobre PDO:

> - Creio que a outra pergunta afirma que sim *"Realmente o PDO é mais lento?"*, mas também afirma que é minimo, algo até supérfluo se comparado.
> - Já pergunta *"Quais seriam os motivos principais de se usar o PDO?"* é ampla demais, geralmente cai no gosto e necessidade.
> - *"Quais são os "diferenciais" do PDO?"* Creio que os diferenciais foi respondido na outra pergunta.
> - *"Por que então usá-lo?"* pra mim isto é o mesmo que a pergunta 2, a resposta é "gosto pessoal" ou "necessidade especifica", o que é amplo demais para se responder.

É minha opinião claro, mas no geral a sua pergunta esta respondida e o resto não dá para responder, porque cai em ser "ampla".

Então entenda que uma hora um fechamento pode cobrir uma pergunta e outra hora não, essa pergunta aqui no meta sua realmente não tem como resolver todos os problemas, porque cada fechamento geralmente "é unico" e tem que analisar caso a caso, ou seja não vai existir uma "uniforme resposta" para esta situação de fechamento que englobe todas, então respostas como:

> todas devem ser fechada mesmo que só cubram 90%

Ou ao contrário

> todas devem ser mantidas abertas porque só cobrem 90%

**Ambas eu considero afirmações erradas**, cada caso é uma caso e deve ser analisado a parte, se o AP discorda do fechamento ele deve editar e evidenciar o que falta e se não conseguir suporte sobre isso leve ao meta, mas como problema especifico e não geral, pois é o que sempre afirmo:

> As perguntas podem ser Fechadas e Reabertas a qualquer momento e justamente por isto existe o META, para resolvermos enganos